# Delay function in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer

I need to understand how can I create delays between a set of commands. My background is with C (DOS) and now reviving the concepts using C# in Visual Studio 2015. This is the code I am struggling with:

```
using System.Threading;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)      // Button
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        textBox1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

I was expecting the background color of the textbox will change alternatively 10 times but I could see only yellow color after the loop finishes. If I increase delay I do notice that program takes time to finish. I went through some related articles but couldn't get the point. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: WinForms is single-threaded and your call to `Thread.Sleep` will block the thread. You must avoid blocking the UI thread. The textbox will only change color when control yields to the `WM_PAINT` window message handler which never happens in your code.

Comment: Have a look on [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in order to learn how to use code block.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an async method to create a delay using the built-in `Task.Delay` method. This will cause execution to be paused and then resumed after the specified time  *without* blocking the current thread.

```
async Task UseDelay()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
```

In your specific case

```
/// <remarks>
/// `async void` is only acceptable because
/// this has to conform to events.
/// Otherwise, we'd use `async Task`.
/// </remarks>
async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;         
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        textBox1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;    
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    }
 }
```

Comment: I used this code and got the desired results. I was also able to apply this philosophy to poll joystick at desired intervals. Thanks to Aluan for the modified code and Chad for the concept,

Answer (score 6):

The problem isn't with the delaying, it's with the threading model of UI applications.  In a UI application, any event handlers happen on the "UI thread".  While that code is running, the UI is essentially frozen, so nothing you do there matters.

That means if you "Sleep" in there, the entire application will lock up and be unresponsive until it returns.

But you can make your event handlers "async void" instead of just "void" if they need to do long running work. Then if you `await Task.Delay(someTime)` instead of `Thread.Sleep(someTime)`, it will release the UI thread while that's happening. And you should see what you expect without the UI locking up.

Also, that time is in milliseconds, meaning wait "one tenth of a second". Which is really, really fast. You might want to slow it down a bit to get the effect you want.